# DataTables warning Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, datatable, datatables

I am sorry if this a  stupid question And I am having a hard time trying to understand this error.
I am getting error at this point.

```
    $('#CustomerTable').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true, //shows jDataTable UI
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "bPaginate": false, //removes pagination
                    "bFilter": false, //removes searchBox
                    "bSort": false, //removes sorting
                    "sDom": 'lfrtip',
                    "bInfo": false, // remove showing records of
                    "bDestroy": true
                });
```

This is what I am getting error at. I searched a lot but could not find anything that works But I am clueless as what exactly is the problem. Please help

Comment: Does your `#CustomerTable` have any `tr`s?   If not, how have you told it where to get the data from?

Comment: DataTables determines which columns to display based on the `thead>tr>th` entries - *try* it without the colspan=13 `tr`, then datatables should be able to determine your columns

Comment: @freedomn-m Removing colspan did not work. Infact its messing with my header and the alert is still there.

Comment: Hi can you share the complete code for `$('#CustomerTable').dataTable()` and your JSON data response? Thanks.

Comment: No - don't remove `colspan=` remove the *whole* `tr`

Comment: @freedomn-m But I want that ``tr`` in my code.

Comment: Is your datatable will call the backend API via ajax? If yes, you may call API via Postman to get the response data. Or show the sample data that you want pass to datatable.

Comment: Hence *try* it - if it works, then that's your issue.  Whether you want it or not, that's not how datatables works.   You can instead specify the columns using the `columns` property, but if you want it to auto-determine the columns, then the columns need to be valid columns.

Comment: That top-row tr could just as easily be a div outside the table, there's no need for it to be in the table, it's not part of the tabular data.

Comment: I don't think you will need <tr> when datatable is applied it will give you a good looking table unless you want <tr> for some other reason than just to set your UI I would recommend removing it.

Comment: This link may help you: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

Comment: @ImdadKhan I have removed ``tr``  the error is still there.

Comment: @freedomn-m  I have removed ``tr`` but the error is still there.

Comment: can you provide the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table class='display unbreakable' border='0' id="CustomerTable" width="100%" style='' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
      <th colspan="13" style="background-color:#666;" align="left">
        <span style="cursor:hand"><img title="Click here to Add" viewtype='add' class="AddItem" onclick="NextPageOpen('General Covenant(s)')" src="../../Images/add.png" /></span>
        <b style="color:white; font-size: 14px;padding: 10px;">Deferral
        <img  src="../../Images/pincomment.png" style='width:20px;cursor:pointer;' onclick="ShowCommentsDiaglog('54','Approval Conditions and Risk Triggers');"  />
        </b>
      </th>
      <th style='width:3%;'>SNO</th>
      <th style='width:10%; display:none'> Activity</th>
      <th style="width:35%">Description</th>
      <th style='width:10%;'> Justification</th>
      <th style='width:10%'> No of Days</th>
      <th style="width:10%;display:none;">Assign To</th>
      <th style='width:10%; display:none'></th>
      <th style='width:10%; display:none'></th>
      <th style='width:10%; display:none'></th>
      <th style='width:10%;'> Decision Action</th>
      <th style='width:10%;'> Status</th>
      <th style='width:10%;'> Type</th>
      <th style="width:25%; display:none">RMG Recommendations</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Considering this how your code looks like after removing . You should first check your data which you are filling in datatable using postman and make sure that it matches your structure.

According to https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4, This might be the reason you are facing this problem.
The number of cells in the table does not satisfy the equation #cells = #columns * #rows (i.e. there are more columns defined in the header than in the table body, or vice-versa).

Comment: check your api data and make sure it matches your structure